# Scalar to array conversion

Tags: perl

I am looking at Perl script and I have a line:

```perl
my (@parmTypesList) = @$function_type_ref;
```

`$function_type_ref` is a string that is passed to the current function.
What does `@$` means ?????

Comment: Are you sure `$function_type_ref` is a string and not a ref?

Comment: The name of an array variable? Sounds like it's not using strict mode, a big no-no.

Comment: See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Symbolic-references if that is the case. The rest of the document if it isn't.

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut might be helpful too.

Comment: Most probable is that `$function_type_ref` holds a reference to an array with function types. `my (@parmTypesList) = @$function_type_ref` operation fills `@parmTypesList` with copy of referenced array. Names of the variables somewht confusing -- `$function_type_ref` against `@parmTypesList`.

Answer (score 1):

`@$var` is short for `@{ $var }` and equivalent to `$var->@*`. It is an array dereference.

It expects `$var` to hold a reference to an array, and it produces one of the following:

- In scalar context, the number of elements of the array
- In list context, the value of the elements of the array.
- When an array is expected (e.g. `@$var = ...`, `push @$var, ...`), the array itself.

In this case, it's the second.

---

Despite the name, in no way would a reference to a function work.

But a string might work, since a string can be used as a reference. In this situation, the string is expected to be the name of the variable. This is a horrible, horrible thing to do, so we tell Perl not to let us do this by using `use strict;` or `use v5.12;`.

Just to be clear: You should ALWAYS use `use strict;` or equivalent.